# how to pass id in controller from form action using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing, codeigniter-form-helper

hey guys i am new in codeigniter,i have a form like this

```
<form class="addinvestmentform" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/ctl_dbcont/input_investment/$id" name="application" method="post" >
//some code
</form>
```

i have a controller methode

```
function input_investment($id)
{
$this->load->helper('form');
                $this->load->helper('html');
                $this->load->model('mod_user');
                $this->mod_user->insertinvestment($id);
}
```

i want to get $id from form action to controller methode how can i do that . . pls help me . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

better to pass the value in the hidden field

```
<form class="addinvestmentform" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/ctl_dbcont/input_investment" name="application" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="my_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
</form>
```

in your ci function

```
function input_investment() {
    $id = $this->input->post('my_id');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->model('mod_user');
    $this->mod_user->insertinvestment($id);
}
```

or if you want (A test)

// Sample view

```
<?php $id = 1; ?>
<form action="<?php echo base_url('my_class/my_method/' . $id); ?>" method="post" >
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

// Controller

```
class My_class extends CI_Controller {

  public function index() {
    $this->load->view('my_class');
  }

  public function my_method($id) {
    echo $id; // outputs 1
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use PHP and echo $id in the  element if you want the value, right now you're sending '$id' to input_investment($id).

```
<form class="addinvestmentform" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/ctl_dbcont/input_investment/<?php echo $id; ?>" name="application" method="post" >
//some code
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your form method is post so you cont get the id through the get method ,you can do like

```
<form class="addinvestmentform" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/ctl_dbcont/input_investment" name="application" method="post" > 
    <input type="hidden" name='id' value="<?php echo $id;?>">
</form>
```

and in your controller you can try with post like

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

or

```
$id = $this->input->post('id');
```

it willl better option for you in all cases if you are trying to send single or multiple data to the controller from an form....

Comment: Sending data through POST instead of GET (or equal methods) has it advantages, but GET has its advantages as well, allowing the user to bookmark the page for example.

Comment: Yeh you are right,I will agree with you but i also told that "for multiple data sending through form is the best option" bec we cont send more values through URL as well ....

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['ctl_dbcont/input_investment/(:num)'] = "ctl_dbcont/input_investment/$1";
```

Just add this line at your config/route :) .

This will work with numbers only, if you have other type of IDs you can use (:any)

Other option is to catch the id directly using :

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

Where segment(3) is the third element after your domain :

```
http://domain/segment1/segment2/segment3
```