# form action URL is not working in php codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

current URL: http://localhost/expressfly/betaversion1/index.php/users/pricing/8/No

when the form is submitted it is supposed to get redirected to a different URL but the URL passed in the form action is getting concatenated to the current URL.

Please note: Form is written in the controller

```
<form id='provider_pay_form' class='form-horizontal' action='index.php/users/reduce_amount/$currentSegment2' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' onsubmit='paynow();'>
```

Comment: <form id='provider_pay_form' class='form-horizontal' action='index.php/users/reduce_amount/$currentSegment2' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' onsubmit='paynow();'>

Comment: give there full path or try ./index.php...

Comment: onsubmit you are directiing to paynow() show your script written in paynow(); or try after removing it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737838/how-to-pass-id-in-controller-from-form-action-using-codeigniter

Comment: Kindly add the whole form code(including paynow() function) to support your question.

Comment: If paynow(); is required as per your current logic then please share your function paynow() with us so we can debug accordingly

Comment: i have given full path now its working fine Thank You

Answer (score 1):

remove this action `onsubmit='paynow();'` and change action like this  `action='<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/users/reduce_amount/'`

set this variable value in hidden field **$currentSegment2** then try to run